# how to disable auto contrast on redmi 10

Tags: screen, xiaomi, screen-brightness, miui

i have this very annoying problem with my redmi 10 (on miui 14.0.5 Global and android 13) where the screen's contrast increases when exposed to sunlight(sometimes even from just my room's light)

have been searching for 2 days about it and it is supposed to be a "feature" ig

i found a lot of people talking about it and its called "sunlight display" i think but what is weird that this feature is from qualcomm and my phone's proccesser is from mediatek idk if this feature is for all phones even if their proccesser isn't from it

anyways i have tried many solutions like disabling auto brightness and sunlight mode and setting current screen colours to standard and it still happens

can someone help me.

(btw i can use adb if there is a way to disable it with adb)

as said in the post tried disabling the sunlight mode and auto brightness and setting screen colours to standard instead of auto but none of them helped with the problem